# Searching for spring dependecies

Tags: java, spring, jar, import, pom.xml

I'm a beginner in spring and I'm trying to develop a simple app however I'm struggling to find a tool which will help me find exactly what jars or what dependencies I should add to my project. I tried

http://search.maven.org/
It worked for some of the jars that I was looking for. It worked for the DriverManagerDataSource however it does not work for the

`org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;`

To be more precise: Is there a tool that will tell me what jars I need for a specific import?

How can I know what jar I need in my build path for the following line of code to compile successfully?

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to use [spring-boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/), so read more about spring-boot here: [getting started](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/).

And see how it is done.

The simplest pom.xml you could have is something like this:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.RC3</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```